# Use JavaScriptCore.framework (jsc) instead of Node.js for non-GUI scripts on macOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, javascriptcore

TL;DR

Is a way to run Node.js scripts using macOS' local javascript interpreter in JavaScriptCore.framework (jsc executable).

---

Long:

I'm willing to write and share a small tool that automatically minifies and compresses text based files in website projects using svgo, uglifyJS2, cssclean and csso for the minification part and zopfli and brotli for the compression part.

Svgo, uglifyJS2, cssclean and csso are all Node.js scripts. During initial research I've stumbled upon several projects that either compile node.js scripts to executables or repack them with a webkit based browser framework. But all those projects also include a certain html/css rendering engine in order to enable the use of guis. Therefore they add a significant overhead (~60-75mb) to the final filesize.

Since svgo, uglifyJS2, cssclean and csso scripts don't require guis, I was wondering if there is a way to run Node.js scripts using macOS' local javascript interpreter in JavaScriptCore.framework (jsc executable).

Comment: You can run any Node.js script from the command line. Add a shebang at the beginning: `#!/usr/bin/env node` – then make the file executable using `chmod`. Does that help you?

Comment: From what I know, JSC has a completely different runtime than Node.js (if it even _has_ a runtime), so I think that's going to be difficult.

Comment: @PatrickHund Target computer may not have node.js installed. So I want to make everything as "portable" as possible and not having to rely on external dependencies. All needed command-line tools and script files packed and distributed in the same app package, if possible.